# 1.3.7.RELEASE -> 1.4.1.RELEASE | java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.showBanner

Tags: java, spring-boot

If I switch to the new version of SpringBoot, I get the above error message when starting the application.
Why is that?

Best wishes
Steven

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.xyz.microservice</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <!--version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version-->
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
                   org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.showBanner(Z)Lorg/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder;
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:109)
at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:75)...
```

**MainClass**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "de.xyzs.microservice")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add more details.

Comment: Well the exception message is pretty clear... What do you thing `NoSuchMethodError` is? ...

Comment: I have added the "pom.xml" file. :-)

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this by explicitly declaring the cloud-context dependency which works for version 1.4.4

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @Suresh , can you help in this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57393814/3301316

Answer (score 4):

When working with Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE, they have changed it from

`new SpringApplicationBuilder().showBanner()`

to

`new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode bannerMode)`

where `Banner.Mode bannerMode`expects an enum for either: Console, Log, or Off.

examples:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE); //Prints banner to System.out

new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.LOG); //Prints banner to the log file

new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF); //Disables the banner
```

If you are looking for the banner to be printed, go with the first one, `Banner.Mode.CONSOLE`

Your new main method would look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //SpringApplicationBuilder() returns an ApplicationContext, but creating the variable is optional
    ApplicationContext ctx = new SpringApplicationBuilder().bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE).run(args);

    //Now, if you need to do something else with the ApplicationContext, you can (such as print all the beans, etc.)
}
```

Here is the java doc to the SpringApplicationBuilder:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html#bannerMode-org.springframework.boot.Banner.Mode-

And here is the java doc explaining the `Banner.Mode` Enum:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/Banner.Mode.html

Comment: How can I influence this? I would just like to work with the current version of Spring ...

Comment: I edited the answer to show what your main method would look like.  You aren't required to store the results of the SpringApplicationBuilder() in a variable,I simply put it there to show you how that would be done.

Comment: @Bwvolleyball, can you help in this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/57393814/3301316

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting the same problem while setting up dummy Producer-  consumer microservice.

Adding below changes in Pom.xml ,was able to solve my problem.

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR6</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Solved this problem by setting one more property - THX :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your Cloud dependencies. I had the same problem and just organize my cloud dependencies goes well.
If you dont use cloud, just exclude cloud transitive dependencies from pom.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem in maven based project while testing the demo for JWT project.

I just removed the version from dependency like below-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

by doing this maven dependency resolver takes the default supported version.

Earlier I was mentioning version **2.1.3.RELEASE** explicitly which caused issue and then I removed the version then it took by default **2.0.3.RELEASE** and worked for me.

Issue resolved.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You get different errors if you use incompatible versions of libraries. So, before doing any troubleshooting, check the versions and make sure to use the compatible versions.

You can refer the below link to check what versions are compatible.

http://start.spring.io/actuator/info

Got this link from one of the SO answers itself: [Is there a compatibility matrix of Spring-boot and Spring-cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659920/is-there-a-compatibility-matrix-of-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud)