# NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-netflix

While trying out Netflix hystrix on Spring boot 2.3.3 gives the following error -
...

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freeMarkerConfigurer' defined in org.springframework.cloud.netflix.hystrix.dashboard.HystrixDashboardConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_INCOMPATIBLE_IMPROVEMENTS
```

Main SimpleClientApplication.java has following annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableHystrixDashboard
```

ProductListController.java
...

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ProductListController {

    @GetMapping
    @HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "defaultProducts")
    public List<String> cloudProductList() {

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8090/products");

        return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, List.class);
    }

    public List<String> defaultProducts() {
        return Arrays.asList("Spring Cloud");
    }
}
```

pom.xml
...

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.3.3.RELEASE

com.demo
simple-client-application
1.0
simple-client-application
Demo project for Spring Boot

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a compatibility matrix of Spring-boot and Spring-cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659920/is-there-a-compatibility-matrix-of-spring-boot-and-spring-cloud)

Comment: It looks like you are using an incompatible version of spring cloud for the spring boot version. Your dependencies show cloud `2.1.0`, but from what you likely need `2.2.0` or newer to be compatible with spring boot `2.3.3`. Specifically, you need the Hoxton releases https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/28/spring-cloud-hoxton-released

Answer (score 0):

I tried many solutions:

- Adjusted maven pom with `freemarker` exclusions and adding explicitly `spring-context-support`.
- Added `spring.freemarker.check-template-location: false`
- Added `spring.freemarker.enabled: false`

and none of these combinations were working for me, at every start of my Spring-Boot App I got the same error you mentioned.

Finally I found that just re-defining the suffix with:

```
spring
  freemarker:
    suffix: .ftl
```

and setting up:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration.class})
```

in my `AppConfig` class (the Class which contains the `@Configuration` annotation), my App is starting after that change.

I have to mention that I use Freemarker without template stored in my App but just using it as a runtime dependency (my Freemarker templates are just texts (Java String) passed in my Class Methods), then I don't really care about the file extensions. I do not want to use the Freemarker auto-configure and I just added the dependency explicitly:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
</dependency>
```