# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/cloud/test/TestSocketUtils after upgrading Spring Boot version to 3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-cloud

I am using the below given dependency in the **build.gradle** for **application tests**:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier:4.0.1'
```

Now when I updated the **Spring Boot** version from `2.x` to `3.x`, I am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for `TestSocketUtils`.

Wondering if anyone has got this issue before?

Comment: Is this Spring Boot? If so please add relevant tags. Also kotlin tag seems irrelevant.

Comment: Also share the stacktrace of the problem.

Comment: Also you might find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42659920/460557 whenever upgrading a framework check for its matrix compatibility. You probably missed some other needed upgrades

Comment: i am using springBootVersion=3.0.11 and springCloudVersion=2022.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add `spring-cloud-test-support` dependency in **build.gradle**:

```
testImplementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-test-support:4.0.1'
```

This has the `org.springframework.cloud.test.TestSocketUtils` class in it.